# Upper Case function does not work on Filtered cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this below function from couple of weeks and i did not realized that when this function is run on the filtered cells.

It copy and paste the irrelevant data on the range where function has ran. I hope someone can help on the issue. I would appreciate the help.

```
`Sub makeUpper(rng As Range)
    Dim v As Long, w As Long, vUPRs As Variant

    With rng
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            ' create array if rng is a single-cell
            ReDim vUPRs(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            vUPRs(1, 1) = .Value2
        Else
            vUPRs = .Value2
        End If

        For v = LBound(vUPRs, 1) To UBound(vUPRs, 1)
            For w = LBound(vUPRs, 2) To UBound(vUPRs, 2)
                vUPRs(v, w) = UCase(vUPRs(v, w))
            Next
        Next

        .Value2 = vUPRs
    End With
End Sub`
```

This function should be run on the file. I have tried to add this line but it does not work `

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
```

`

**Before Applying the code:**

[image]

**After Applying the code:**

[image]

Comment: You cannot assign a broken range to a variant array in bulk.  You will need to iterate the areas and each cell in those areas adding them one by one to the array, then reverse that when putting them back, so it would probably be quicker to just deal with the cells using a `For Each` loop instead.

Comment: Alright thanks for sharing your thoughts but it is something beyond my knowledge. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Upper-Case a Discontinuous Range

```
Sub MakeUpper(ByVal rng As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rng.Worksheet
    Dim arg As Range
    For Each arg In rng.Areas
        arg.Value = ws.Evaluate("=UPPER(" & arg.Address & ")")
    Next arg
End Sub
```

- If you want to stick with the array solution, you could use the following.

```vb
Sub MakeUpperArray(ByVal rng As Range)
    
    Dim arg As Range, vUPRs, vUPR, v As Long, w As Long
    
    For Each arg In rng.Areas
        With arg
            If .CountLarge = 1 Then
                ' create array if rng is a single-cell
                ReDim vUPRs(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
                vUPRs(1, 1) = .Value2
            Else
                vUPRs = .Value2
            End If
    
            For v = 1 To UBound(vUPRs, 1)
                For w = 1 To UBound(vUPRs, 2)
                    vUPR = vUPRs(v, w)
                    If VarType(vUPR) = vbString Then
                        vUPRs(v, w) = UCase(vUPR)
                    End If
                Next w
            Next v
    
            .Value2 = vUPRs
        End With
    Next arg

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer I updated the function back in November because I apply this on large dataset but above answer is slow as well and it did not mean that your answer is not worthy. Thanks

Comment: I appreciate your continuous help but problem is still same i have added 2 pictures in the question which may help better to understand my problem. @VBasic2008

Comment: Sorry for bothering but you need to disregard my last comment since in my sample with 5k areas in 20k rows it took 10s for `...SpecialCells...`, 10s for `ws.AutoFiltermode = False` and another 10s for either function. The problem is that it's slow with either version when there are many areas. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74841436) to a solution that uses helper columns to get the data into three areas so it can be processed much faster. Not sure if this applies here since you didn't share how exactly you are filtering the data.

Comment: Alright so let me explain. I have data with more than 100K rows when i use this function on all data without applying the filter it works perfectly but whenever create filter and select necessary records then if i apply this functions it copies and paste the above data below as you can see in picture. It should work on for `visible rows`